# Soft ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, cascade

I am familiar with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` method, but I don't want to do a real delete, just a soft delete. This is implemented with a column named *isDeleted* (0/1).

Is there a way for me to cascade this soft delete from a parent to a child? A built in command? or is up to me to write the code?

I am thinking that what I am doing is in fact an update. So I'd be using an `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, but will that update the same columns on the FKs? or just the primary key?

Comment: Yes, `ON UPDATE CASCADE` will update only the columns used in the FK definition. If you make the `(ParentID, isDeleted)` unique in the parent table and you use that in the FK, it will work (update the `isDeleted` as well in the child table). But I'm not sure if this is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

For what you are describing you would want to use a trigger on the table where you want the soft delete to cascade from.

Here are a few references on triggers:

[MSSQLTips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2911/working-with-triggers/)

[Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Triggers have their place but they can quickly get out of hand when triggers fire other triggers or when the trigger execution takes a significant amount of time to complete.

Additionally performance degradation can be a factor with triggers as they happen synchronous when an insert/update/delete statement is made on the table which can extend the execution time of the statement.

[Microsoft's Nested triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178101.aspx)

[Info from Paul White on triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111613/sql-server-after-insert-trigger-does-not-perform-actions)

[DML triggers for multiple data rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190752.aspx)